# Notepad++ switch to weird editing mode

Tags: notepad++

I'm using notepad++ to edit a file.

Every now and then it seems to switch mode, a bit like vim would do.

In this mode when I press escape, it will write a special `esc` character.

So far I haven't found what seems to trigger this mode, what it does and most importantly how to exit it. This means I have to restart notepad++ every time.

Is there anyway to avoid that ?

[image]

Comment: Can you share us a screenshot of this "weird editing mode"?

Comment: I hope the snapshot helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ESC** can be printed in Notepad++ by pressing Shift + Esc. See: [Notepad++ Weird Characters](http://tnbforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=124&t=25015)

It could be that somehow Notepad++ is getting the Shift modifier with all your key-presses. It could be a mechanical error or some issue with remote desktop, VCN, Synergy or similar tools.

As far as I know Notepad++ has no modes akin to Vim.

Comment: Good point. I had an old keyboard with faulty springs, the space and shift buttons were getting randomly stuck!